# SQL, XML Inserting multiple nodes

Tags: sql, xml, insert, nodes

I have the following xml that I want to insert into a database

```
<latestjourneys>
    <journey>
        <startLocation>London</startLocation>
        <endLocation>manchester</endLocation>
        <leavingDay>
             <mon>Yes</mon>
             <tue>No</tue>
        </leavingday>
    <journey>
    <journey>
        <startLocation>Liverpool</startLocation>
        <endLocation>Cardiff</endLocation>
        <leavingDay>
             <mon>Yes</mon>
             <tue>No</tue>
        </leavingday>
    <journey>
</latestjourneys>
```

I am using the following sql

```
INSERT INTO test (startLocation,endLocation,mon,tue)
SELECT 
X.product.query('startLocation').value('.', 'VARCHAR(255)'),
X.product.query('endLocation').value('.', 'VARCHAR(255)'),
X.product.query('Mon').value('.', 'VARCHAR(255)'),
X.product.query('Tue').value('.', 'VARCHAR(255)')
FROM (
SELECT CAST(x AS XML)
 FROM OPENROWSET(
 BULK '#fileLocation#',
 SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)
) AS T(x)
 CROSS APPLY x.nodes('latestjourneys/journey') AS X(product)
```

When I use this code only the startLocation and endLocation get inserted. When I change the CROSS APPLY to

```
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('latestjourneys/journey/leavingDay') AS X(product)
```

only the days get inserted.

is there a way I can insert both pieces of data?

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like XML support is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: Also: your XML is invalid - the closing tag for `<leavingDay>` needs to be `</leavingDay>` (capitalization matters!), and the `<journey>` nodes aren't closed at all - their "closing" tag is `<journey>` again - doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or newer - you could use something like this:

```
SELECT
    StartLocation = Journey.value('(startLocation)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    EndLocation = Journey.value('(endLocation)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    LeaveMon = Leaving.value('(mon)[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
    LeaveTue = Leaving.value('(tue)[1]', 'varchar(10)')
FROM
    X.nodes('/latestjourneys/journey') AS Nodes(Journey)
CROSS APPLY
    Journey.nodes('leavingDay') AS Subnode(Leaving)
```

Basically, the first `.nodes()` call gives you a list of all `<journey>` elements - and then from each of those elements, you need to call `.nodes()` again to get all elements in the `<leavingDay>` subnode.

Answer (score 0):

declare @temp table ( id int, guid uniqueidentifier )

declare @XMlData as xml;

set @XMlData = 'paste your xml here'

insert into @temp (id, guid) SELECT XTbl.Cats.value('.', 'int'), newid() FROM @XMlData.nodes('/users/user') AS XTbl(Cats)

select * from @temp

output:

id    guid
10    12FF8543-D98C-4CF3-BA0B-CD4CFEF5A0C3
20    F6244519-F40E-4E28-9C91-5832E7F45A70
30    6775BED5-1127-4D8E-88D2-ECE9CED55056

Answer (score -1):

hmm.. I thought that the value function will return the value of the node using an XPath expression so maybe doing something like:

```
X.product.value('/latestjourneys/journey/leavingDay')
```

I'm not really familiar with SQL's XML support but I hope this helps.

You can also check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117%28v=sql.90%29.aspx